# Powershell Encoded Command not executing

Tags: powershell, windows-10, installshield, group-policy

I have a powershell script that runs as part of an installshield installer on a machine with Windows 10. Powershell version (Major: 5, Minor: 1, Build 17134, Revision 112). Dev machine (where everything works fine) (Major: 5, Minor: 1, Build 15063, Revision 1155)

Basically, a .bat script runs an encoded powershell command, but it is not executing, I simplified it down to a simple script to show what I am talking about:

Powershell Script:

```
$text="Write-Output Hello"
$encoded=[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($text))

Write-Output "Trying encoded command:"
powershell -EncodedCommand $encoded

Write-Output "Trying not encoded command:"
powershell $text
```

This is the output:

```
Trying encoded command:
Trying not encoded command:
Hello
```

I also added a decoded statement to do an additional check:

```
$decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($encoded))
Write-Output "Decoded:"
Write-Output $decoded
```

Output:

```
Trying encoded command:
Trying not encoded command:
Hello
Decoded:
Write-Output Hello
```

The execution policy is set to "Bypass", i'm just wondering if there is something in the windows registry/settings/security/group policies/etc. that will block encoded commands like this? Why does it work in plain text but not encoded? Could the Powershell version have anything to do with it?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?  Try putting `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';` in `$text` and retry.  You can also check the event viewer to see if any heuristics might be running?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I place it as the first line in the script? I didn't see any errors when I did this.

Comment: Your original commands work for me. Do you have an antivirus engine blocking encoded commands?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler How can I check that?

Comment: Have you got any AV software installed and does it show anything being blocked in its console?

Comment: I've removed my "use quotes" answer as this doesn't make a difference. That came from a different type of scenario I've encountered in the past. You need to check for the likes of AV interfering because I don't have this problem either. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a block from the AV on encoded commands. Thank you @TessellatingHeckler